# WCF SOAP Action is incorrect

Tags: wcf, soap, soapheader

I have a WCF client calling a Java SOAP service (with TLS and MA incidentally).

The SOAP action is coming out as:

```
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>
```

But I am trying to set it to

```
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">urn:example:services:201005:SendMessage</a:Action>
```

I thought I could do this using the following OperationContract attribute...

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:example:ns:201005", ConfigurationName = "IExampleService")]
public interface IExampleService : IDisposable
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "urn:example:services:201005:SendMessage")]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ExampleErrorInfo), Action = "urn:example:services:201005:SendMessage", Name = "ExampleErrorInfo")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(SupportFaults = true)]
    ExampleResponse SendMessage(ExampleRequest request);
}
```

Why is my SOAP action still wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are talking about a WCF client..

Comment: Well, it is both - but for the purposes of this question it is the client.

Comment: Shouldn't the action contain the service namespace? (e.g. urn:example:ns:201005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a WS-Trust handshake message, not your actual message. See http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/tls/WSTrustForTLS.pdf , section 1.8.

Comment: Well spotted. It is the handshake message that is exploding the Java service. Thanks.